# Precision recall datasets

Tags: information-retrieval, text-classification

Can anyone point me at datasets of precision and recall generated by binary classifiers at different confidence levels?

I'm not trying to develop a classifier. I'm doing an empirical investigation into common patterns that emerge when these data sets are evaluated.

Ideally, what I'd like are three columns: precision, recall, confidence threshold. Alternatively, precision and recall could be replaced by the four underlying tallies: true positives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives.

I could also work from lists of ranked results where each result is flagged as true or false.

The actual classifiers and source data sets aren't that important but I would like to know what they are.

Many thanks in advance.